# No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from

Tags: maven, version-control, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to use maven release plugin and after that automate this using nexus.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ozge.net</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ozge.net</artifactId>
  <version>1.1- snapshot</version>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins> 
       <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.1</version>
       <configuration>
       <tagBase>svn://local/exekuce/com.ozge.net</tagBase>
      </configuration>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

  </build>
    <scm>
   <tag>HEAD</tag>
   <connection>scm:svn:svn://[svnusername]:[svn password]@local/exekuce/com.ozge.net</connection>
   <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://[svnusername]:[svn password]@local/exekuce/com.ozge.net</developerConnection>
   <url>scm:svn:svn://[svnusername]:[svn password]@local/exekuce/com.ozge.net</url>
</scm>
  <distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>OzgeRelease</id>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/OzgeRelease</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

after I ran the command `mvn release:perform` on command prompt

it says

> No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from

I believe I provided.

Anybody here tried to maven-subversion-nexus-hudson for automating builds?

Comment: Did you do a `mvn release:prepare` first?

Comment: yes i did without a problem. There was an error in my settings.xml about nexus server id. I corrected it now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Try to perform `release:clean` first.

> mvn release:clean

Then try again.